# React-JS StripeCheckout get the Customer ID/Charge ID after successful purchase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the  Customer ID/Charge ID after the purchase and  to send the  Customer ID/Charge ID in database for future use.

```
 import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
     onToken = async (token) => {}
      <StripeCheckout
       stripeKey='pk_test_51JG'
        token={this.onToken}
        amount={this.state.grandTotal * 100}
        name='Payment'/>
```

Comment: what's the question and where you do struggle at?

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way is to set up a webhook endpoint and subscribe to `checkout.session.completed` events: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#handle-the-event

Depending on what exactly you mean by "transaction ID" the information you need is likely already contained there, or can be retrieved from Stripe using the IDs available.

Comment: I need  stripe charge id or customer Id, onToken = async (token)=>{} In token response only, I get card ID. How to get Charge id or Customer ID?